# SHA256 using Openssl causes segmentation fault

Tags: c, hash, segmentation-fault

I'm trying to encrypt files using AES and based on forward secrecy principe by computing the new key of encryption which is the hash of the old key. So I'm using the openssl implementation for hash function SHA256.
First I wanted to test the feasibility of this with this simple code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <openssl/sha.h>

 int main()
 {
     unsigned char *key =(unsigned char *)"01234567890123456789012345678901";
     SHA256(key, strlen(key), key);
     return 0;
  }
```

But a segmentation fault occurs what can be the reason ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your string literal is placed in read-only memory and when openssl tries to write to it, your program gets the segmentation fault.

Language-wise, attempting to modify string literals is causing undefined behavior.

Either create a buffer for your input key or create a new buffer for the output.

Comment: How do you know it is in read-only memory? A PC typically only has a boot/BIOS Flash which is read-only, the rest is RAM. It is at the discretion of the user not to change a string literal, it is not enforced by the implementation.

Comment: @Olaf It is enforced by the implementation by placing the data in a region of virtual memory that is protected with read-only access rights. Not as a security measure, but for safety of the program. Of course the process itself has enough privileges to change this protection if it wants with mprotect/VirtualProtect.

Comment: Please provide a reference to where the C standard has such a requirement. Until then: this is simply UB; it is not know what specifically happens without possibly knowing the environment. Note that the standard explicitly mentions an extension to have string literals modifyable (which we also don't know about, so let's leave it at UB).

Comment: @Olaf I think I pretty clearly separated my answer into explanation of his error and what the standard says.

Answer (score 0):

C string literals are effectively `char const*` (although they're `char *`, technically, for compatibility reasons). You should not write to them. If you do, the behavior of your program will be undefined.

Anyway, `SHA256` from `#include <openssl/sha.h>` is:

```
unsigned char *SHA256(const unsigned char *d, size_t n,unsigned char *md);
```

So to use it, you should do something like:

```
char const *key = "01234567890123456789012345678901";
unsigned char buf[256/CHAR_BIT]; //or SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH
SHA256((unsigned char const*)key, strlen(key), buf);
```

You can then print the result with:

```
 for(int i=0;i<sizeof(buf);i++)
     printf("%.2hhx", buf[i]);
```

(assuming 8 bit chars).

Comment: Thanks for the answer but in this context I want to hash the key recursively in a way that the next key is the hash of the actual key, the problem here is that the input and output of SHA256 are different types.

Comment: @Amed: Applying the same hash algorithm on a hash does not make sense. What problem do you **think** to solve with this?

Comment: @Olaf I want to apply hash on hash in order to obtain forward secrecy : The new key is the hash of the old key and so on and so forth. I am using this new key to encrypt data and then generate the new key which is the hash of the old one ....

Comment: @Amed: I'm not sure this is a good approach with SHA. Typically one uses e.g. AES to get such pseudorandom-numbers. But this sounds like a bad idea in general: if one key is broken, you can get the next key just from that one if you know the algorithm (and secrecy by obscurity never really works).